# What is the meaning of UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in jest tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, promise, jestjs

ant to test the following module `index.ts`

```
async function theFunctionFail() {
  return await fail();
}

async function theFunctionSucceed() {
  return await succeed();
}

async function fail() {
  throw new Error();
}

async function succeed() {
  return "a";
}

export { theFunctionFail, theFunctionSucceed };
```

using a test `index.test.ts`

```
import { theFunctionFail, theFunctionSucceed } from "../index";

it('theFunctionFail', () => {
  expect(theFunctionFail()).rejects;
});
```

What does the `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` in the output

```
(node:10515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
(node:10515) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:10515) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
 PASS  src/__tests__/index.test.ts
  ✓ theFunctionFail (6ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.806s
Ran all test suites.
```

refer to? Wrapping `expect(theFunctionFail()).rejects` in a `try-catch(err)` block doesn't avoid the warning which I consider worth fixing.

Why don't the test fail?/How can I make the tests fail? If my test discovered a severe flaw, it shouldn't succeed in my understanding.

I'm using Typescript and Jest 24.7.1 with `react-scripts`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This warning refers to the fact that an error is happening in the test that isn't being handled. The real problem is that your test isn't testing anything - there's an `expect` without a matcher. Here's what it should be:

```
return expect(theFunctionFail()).rejects.toEqual(new Error());
```

See the Jest docs for `.rejects`: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects

Note: It's also possible to use `try/catch`, but you have to either `await` like this:

```
it('theFunctionFail', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  try {
    await theFunctionFail();
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err).toEqual(new Error());
  }
});
```

Or return the async function and catch the error (make sure you return the function):

```
it('theFunctionFail', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  return theFunctionFail().catch(err => {
    expect(err).toEqual(new Error());
  });
});
```

`expect.assertions(number)` is a good way to make sure all of your `expect`s are being called when testing asynchronous behavior.

Also, if you add an error message, e.g. `new Error('oh no!')`, you will know for sure that you're catching the right error, and will make it a bit easier to debug.

Comment: Is there a way to more easily find the offending test? Is there a temporary monkey-patch that I can do? I have over 1000 for this one project, and the error doesn't line up with where it's displayed in the output.

Comment: It sounds like your issue might be in your code, rather than your tests. I would make sure your code doesn’t have any promises that don’t have a `.catch`, or any `await`s outside of a `try/catch`

Comment: Right. I just don’t know how to find it in the code without painstakingly running every test individually.

Comment: hi, wondering if you found a way to identify the offending test? or to reproduce this in your local jest run? Our jest quits only in our CI pipeline, everything seems fine in local

Comment: It's worth explicitly pointing out that the `return` in the above answer is critical - this tells jest to wait for the promise to resolve or reject before determining the test's result.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution that does not produce an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in the console is to use jest's [expect.toThrow()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) function.

```js
import { theFunctionFail, theFunctionSucceed } from "../index";

it('theFunctionFail', () => {
  expect(theFunctionFail()).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

And again you can try to match a specific error. E.g. if:

```js
async function fail() {
  throw new Error('Something failed');
}
```

then, you would test with:

```js
it('theFunctionFail', () => {
  expect(theFunctionFail()).rejects.toThrow(Error('Something failed'));
});
```